# Could You Boil Water from Blood?

Tags: hematology

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blood#Plasma)...

> About 55% of blood is blood plasma, a fluid that is the blood's liquid
>   medium, which by itself is straw-yellow in color. The blood plasma
>   volume totals of 2.7–3.0 liters (2.8–3.2 quarts) in an average human.
>   It is essentially an aqueous solution containing 92% water, 8% blood
>   plasma proteins, and trace amounts of other materials.

Does this mean it would be possible to boil water from blood for consumption? For example, in The Walking Dead, Rick and the gang are dehydrated and without water. When a pack of wild dogs confronts them, they kill them and cook them for consumption. Could they have collected the blood, boiled it, and used some sort of contraption to catch the clean, vaporized water?

Comment: It seems possible, vaporization can work for this.

Comment: This question doesn't make sense. Any substance that contains water can be vaporised and the water later distilled.

Comment: @MarchHo I agree with you, but I am still impressed by how Zulfe could think about this disgusting but interesting topic ;)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic

Comment: Seems ok to me. It's framed properly in a biological context

Comment: This question is rather about chemistry and methods to seperate water from other liquid. Distillation is probably the solution indeed.